# Timed jQuery rotation

Tags: javascript, jquery, rotation, jquery-tabs

I'm trying to make the selector rotate at varying times, I figured I would try a simple if/else statement, to make the first one rotate after 3 seconds, and the following ones after 30 seconds. However, it just keeps rotating it every three seconds. Had I figured how to make this work, I was planning on adding more if/else statements inside the previous one, so that I could add custom times for each slide. Any ideas how I could achieve this?

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var flipped = false;

      if (!flipped)
      {
         $('#Blog1 > ul').tabs({fx:{opacity: 'toggle'}});
         $('#Blog1 > ul').tabs('rotate', 3000, true);
         flipped = true;
      }
      else
      {
         $('#Blog1 > ul').tabs({fx:{opacity: 'toggle'}});
         $('#Blog1 > ul').tabs('rotate', 30000, true);
      }
});
```

Comment: Why are you using `&gt;`? it should be `>`

Comment: Blogger changes > to &gt; if I save, exit the code, and then return back to it. I forgot to change it back. (I'll edit the code.)

Answer (score 0):

You're clearly setting "flipped" to false every time you run the function.
Or rather, your not running it again to check for flipped. (I think)

You need to separate the variable from the function, otherwise it will always be false.

As for time, you can easily use **Math.random()**

```
randomNumber = Math.floor((Math.random() * 30) + 1); // Random number between 1 and 30
$('#Blog1 > ul').tabs({fx:{opacity: 'toggle'}});
$('#Blog1 > ul').tabs('rotate', randomNumber, true);
```

Comment: Would it be possible to make it so that the variable `number` would loop, and depending on which loop it was through, it would edit the number? I need the time to be exact for each slide.

The reason is that each slide contains a paragraphs of varying lengths, and I need to set the duration of each tab, so that it stays for long enough time for the text to be read. But I don't want it to be static, because some of the paragraphs are short.